# Implicit Differentiation - Can't spot my error

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I can't figure out where I went wrong in finding the derivative for this function.  Can anyone spot my error?

$2(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 25(x^2 - y^2)$

$4(x^2 + y^2)(2x + 2yy') = 25(2x - 2yy')$

$\displaystyle \frac{2x + 2yy'}{2x - 2yy'} = \frac{25}{4(x^2 + y^2)}$

$2x + 2yy' = 25$

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{25 - 2x}{2y}$

On the initial line is the function I'm differentiating; the rest is the process of differentiation.

Comment: Your fourth line doesn't follow from your third that I can tell. (It amounts to equating the numerators of the third line which isn't valid unless the denominators also agree.)

Comment: @Semiclassical  Of course.  Thank you semiclassical.

Answer (score 1):

$$4(x^2+y^2)2(x+y')=25\cdot2(x-y')$$

$$\frac{x+y'}{x-y'}=\frac{25}{4(x^2+y^2)}$$

Applying Componendo and dividendo,

$$\frac{y}x'=\frac{25-4(x^2+y^2)}{25+4(x^2+y^2)}$$

Comment: (upvoted!) What is Componendo and dividendo :o

Comment: @Tharindu, Please google it

Comment: Sure ;))))))))))